# How to make the footer stay at auto position with respect to the component's height?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to keep the footer component at the end of my `router-outlet`. The problem is, when using this code

```
:host {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

the footer stays at the bottom, but acts as `fixed` footer. But I want the footer to change its position w.r.t. the `router-outlet`'s size. Changing to `position: relative` makes it go down and I have to scroll down. The picture below will give the detail about this:

[image]

You can see the page gone down.

My responsive topbar component has the following code:

```
.mat-toolbar {
  height: 7vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.mat-sidenav-container {
  background-color: white;
  height: 93vh !important;
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

What I am thinking is that probably the `height` of `mat-sidenav-container` is causing the problem.
Please help me out in this scenario.
This is my sample [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsju4v?).

Comment: make the complete code, pls. html and css

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I've updated my question with a sample you can check now

Answer (score 1):

The `topbarComponent` is not just a Div placed at the top, it covers the entire screen. `RouterOutlet` and `footerComponent` must be defined in `mat-sidenav-content`.

As per to the given stackBlits, use below code:-

```
<mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
   // Awesome content within router-outlet
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Keep Position CSS property as **Default/unset**  for footerComponent i.e. relative;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it using Grid? Add the following code to your CSS:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: max-content max-content 1fr max-content;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
```